# Select checkbox using input tag and non standard attribute values using python selenium

Tags: selenium

I want to select a checkbox with the HTML code shown below using the attribute bayid:

```
<input type="checkbox" devid="bay" bayid="10" checked="">
```

I could get the XPath information - "//*[@id="svbSelectEnc1"]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[3]/input", but I want to use the **bayid** for selecting as there are lot of checkboxes in the form of a table and only specific checkboxes have to be selected that are read from the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using CSS Selector or XPath as shown below.

By CSS Selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[bayid='10']")).click();
```

By XPath

```
//input[@bayid='10']
```

Also I would suggest you to go through basic tutorial on how to find WebElement using [CSS Selector](http://learn-automation.com/write-dynamic-css-selector-in-selenium/) and [XPath](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-write-dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

try the following XPath:

```
//input[@bayid='10']
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector way to do this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("yourTagName[attribute='attributeValue']")).click();
```

For your specific case:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[bayid='10']")).click();
```